# How do I call this function c

Tags: c, gnu

First apologize for asking this dumb question:

How to call this function in c (GNU C)

```
char *ftoa(float f, char *buf, int places)
```

Comment: I don't believe that's GNU C (and certainly not standard C). Why don't you use `sprintf` or something like that?

Comment: As above plus you've tagged as ARM, so I can see performance reasons why you don't want to use sprintf but more details on the target / compiler are needed.

Comment: So you don't know the syntax of calling a function? I don't understand.

Comment: Yes that is right , I do not know the syntax for calling this funciton , specifically I am confused of pointer  return and  *buf parameter

Comment: @TonyP, please tell us exactly where you found that function, this is definitively not part of the gnu C library nor of the C standard and has nothing to do with ARM.

Comment: Sorry I did not mention earlier,
I am trying my hands on ARM Cortex M processor using GNU C toolchain and CooCox IDE.

Comment: TonyP, when you reply to a comment, you should place an "@" followed by the username of the person you want to reply to. Like Jens did with "@TonyP". If you don't do this, that person will not see your reply in his notifications.

Comment: @Jens, Yes, this is not standard lib function, Purpose of this function is to rewrite printf function to accommodate float type as an string. This (user) function takes the float and returns a pointer to char buffer , which then can be used to transmit string to a device.

Comment: @Mat, Yes you are right , I hope I did not say this is a GNU C function. What I meant is to say I want to call this function using GNU C. Perhaps the question was too dumb or presented that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you call it:

```
int decimal_places = 10;
char* result = malloc(decimal_places + 1);
ftoa(SOME_FLOAT_VALUE, result, decimal_places);
```

The function returns its `buf` argument. As always, don't forget to free() the `result` string when you're done with it.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer:

```
#define DECIMALS 10
char result[DECIMALS+1];
ftoa(SOME_FLOAT_VALUE, result, decimal_places);
```

I too would suggest using sprintf for greater flexibility.

The reason I prefer static allocation is that this will take up less space, it is automatically de-allocated when you leave the function [if that's not what you want, obviously, you may need malloc, but on stack allocation for small variabls, and 11 bytes is small!, should be the preferred way. I see WAY too much code with meaningless allocations - it wastest memory, and adds extra code. [The overhead of allocating 11 bytes from the heap is probably more than 11 bytes, as it will have to be rounded to 12 bytes, then a 'header' to account for the allocation, which in many systems is 16 or 32 bytes, in some cases 12 bytes]

Answer (score 0):

I think the GNU implementation of C doesn't have a predefined function ftoa()

You could use sprintf() as follows :

```
float f;
char *a = (char *)malloc(10*sizeof(char)); //assuming you need 10 characters to store f
sprintf(a, "%f", f);
```

If you want to have only a specific number of decimal places, you could use "%0.2f" (for two digits after decimal point) etc. instead of "%f"

sprintf() could come in handy instead of the itoa() function. For example:

```
char *a = (char *)malloc(10*sizeof(char);
int x = 10;
float f = 12.4;
sprintf(a, "%d", x);  //=itoa() function
sprintf(a, "%f", f);
```

Good luck!